How to "run code through Rollup first, then pass it to Babel"?
To quote the top of the readme for @rollup/plugin-babel:

If you're using Babel to transpile your ES6/7 code and Rollup to generate a standalone bundle, you have a couple of options:

run the code through Babel first, being careful to exclude the module transformer, or
run the code through Rollup first, and then pass it to Babel.


By default, using the recommended option babelHelpers: "bundled", @rollup/plugin-babel appears to be running Babel during the build process, as each file is read. I would like to implement the second option, let Rollup bundle the files, then pass the bundle to Babel for transpilation. But I don't see a way to do it.
It occurs to me that I could write a Rollup plugin that runs Babel in a buildEnd hook. But:

How do I prevent Babel from running during the build?
How do I run Babel from inside that hook function?

The plugin readme makes it sound so simple, but it never describes how to implement it. How can I accomplish this?
This is my first automated javascript build, and I'm just getting to know these various tools and processes. My current setup is Gulp/Rollup/Babel+Terser. I can do it in Gulp but it forces me to use intermediate files instead of a stream, as explained here.
Obviously I'd prefer to avoid intermediate files, so it would be better to resolve this in Rollup/Babel. If not, I could either:

Use a bundler other than Rollup, or
Use a task manager other than Gulp

Final Result: @Timur's link to farther down that readme page solved it for me. Terser doesn't do it the way I want, but SWC does, and the rollup-plugin-swc-minify plugin does it out-of-the-box: "Simpler than rollup-plugin-swc, focusing only on minification of the bundled JavaScript output." For my small, initial project it minifies better than Tersify and certainly better than Babel minify.
It's not initially working in Gulp using the Rollup API, but I can always run it via CLI, even within Glup.

Sidestepping the problem: use esbuild so you don't need separate bundling and transpilation steps. With the bonus of things running much faster than rollup or babel can.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - I want separate bundling and transpilation steps because of one specific transpile (a custom babel plugin). I either need to control the order of the files going in, or I need them bundled so that it's all in one place already. The plugin has collections that map to entire class families, so it needs to parse the superclasses first (or get a lot more complicated). I'm sure I can achieve similar things in esbuild.  In the moment I'm already down this path, so I'm going to wait to see if there's a reasonable solution available. And build speed is not a concern.

It would be appropriate to create an issue in the cited repository about the lack of explicit instruction in its readme file. The maintainer(s) can update the readme or you can contribute a PR to do so after they answer your questions. As it stands, this seems to ask, "How do I write a custom Rollup plugin implementation that does x?"… which isn't exactly a focused question — take a look at the documentation for the Rollup output generation hook generateBundle.

@jsejcksn - Thanks for the suggestions. I submitted this issue: https://github.com/rollup/plugins/issues/1809.  As for the generateBundle hook, I still don't have a way to prevent Babel from running during the bundle generation process.  Unless I'm missing something.

https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/babel#running-babel-on-the-generated-code

@Timur - Thanks! That does it inside rollup.config.js and inside Gulp. I guess I needed a translator for that readme. Since posting this I have switched away from Babel preset-minify to Terser, so I'll have to see if @rollup/plugin-terser has the same behavior. But your comment answers the question, so if you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.
